# What is wrong wth this pstricks code?

Tags: pstricks

I'm a newbie so the answer is probably quite simple.

I have the code below and its giving me two issues:

1. The x and y axis labels are in random places?
2. The supplied co-ordinates are not being rendered at the
   correct co-ordinates.

CORRECTION:

2. The supplied co-ordinates are not being rendered at the INCORRECT co-ordinates.

Any advice/help/tips much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
    \psset{xAxisLabel=LABELX,yAxisLabel=LABELY, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.8},yAxisLabelPos={-0.06,c},xunit=40cm,yunit=0.1cm}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,70)(0.0,10.0)
    \psgrid[subgriddiv=1, gridcolor=white,griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt]
    \psaxes[Dx=0.05, Dy=10, labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle](0,0)(0,0)(0.251,100.0) 
    \begin{psgraph}[](0.25,0.9){5cm}{1cm}
    \psline[linewidth=1.0pt, showpoints=true, dotstyle=o, fillcolor=cyan](0.240608234,0)(0.209576383,1)(0.206539843,2)(0.190312769,3)
    \end{psgraph}
    \end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than adding a message in the space reserved for answer, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
    \psset{xAxisLabel=Similarity score,yAxisLabel=Number correct, xAxisLabelPos={c,-10},yAxisLabelPos={-0.03,c},xunit=40cm,yunit=1cm}
    \begin{psgraph}[Dx=0.1,Dy=10](0,0)(0,0)(0.25,100){10cm}{10cm}
    \psline[linewidth=1.0pt](0.240608234,0)(0.209576383,1)(0.206539843,2)
    \end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres the answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-plot,filecontents}
\begin{document}
\psset{xAxisLabel=Similarity score,yAxisLabel=Number correct, xAxisLabelPos={c,-10},yAxisLabelPos={-0.06,c},xunit=40cm,yunit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, gridcolor=white,griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt]
\begin{psgraph}[Dx=0.1,Dy=10](0,0)(0,0)(0.25,100){10cm}{10cm}
\psline[linewidth=1.0pt, showpoints=false, dotstyle=o, fillcolor=cyan](0.240608234,0)(0.209576383,1)(0.206539843,2)
\end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).